# ElasticSearch retrieve more recent X lines using NEST

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I want to retrieve more recent X lines from elasticsearch using NEST, but when I use .Sort() it will return 0 documents. If I remove Sort() it will return documents but not the most recent ones.

Any idea how to retrieve most recent logs lines from elastic or what i am doing wrong?

```
var result = elk.Search<FileBeatDto>(x => x
        .From(0)
        .Index("filebeat-*")                
        .Type(type)                               
        .Query(q => 
            q.Match(qs => qs.Field("fields.asset_tag").Query(asset_tag)) &&
            q.Match(qs => qs.Field("message").Query(filter))
            )
        .Take(lines)
        .Sort(ss => ss.Descending(p => p.timestamp))
        );
```

Comment: What does `FileBeatDto` look like? and what does the mapping for the `type` type look like?

Answer (score 0):

timestamp and version are retrieved as null. Not sure it is because in elastic they are @timestamp and @version.

```
public class FileBeatDto
{
    public DateTime timestamp { get; set; }
    public string datetime { get; set; }
    public DateTime received_at { get; set; }
    public int offset { get; set; }
    public string version { get; set; }
    public string input_type { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }
    public Beat beat { get; set; }
    public string host { get; set; }
    public string source { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public object fields { get; set; }
    public List<string> tags { get; set; }
}
```

type is well defined to the type of document that is not the problem if i remove the sort it returns the documents fine.

I get this error: No mapping found for [timestamp] in order to sort on